# MongoDB insert object inside an object

Tags: mongodb, json

Please suggest me on how to insert an object inside an object.
Sample collection

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57556cec9d66a6c26b19ce06"),
"email" : "david@gmail.com",
"password" : "1235466",
"typeOfUser" : 1,
"userDetails" : {
    "firstName" : "David",
    "lastName" : "Beckham",
    "contactNumber" : "12345678989"
}
```

}

I would like to add another object called address object inside this.
something like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57556cec9d66a6c26b19ce06"),
"email" : "david@gmail.com",
"password" : "1235466",
"typeOfUser" : 1,
"userDetails" : {
    "firstName" : "David",
    "lastName" : "Beckham",
    "contactNumber" : "12345678989"
     "address" : {
        "country" : "",
        "state" : ""
     }
  }
```

}

Please suggest me on how to insert values for address object..

What I have tried?

db.getCollection('PetCare').update({"contactNumber":"12345678989"},{"$push":{"address":{"country":"India","city":"Blore"}}})

but it does not update..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
db.getCollection('PetCare').update({"userDetails.contactNumber":"12345678989"},{"$set":{"userDetails.address":{"country":"India","city":"Blore"}}})
```

Answer (score 3):

The `$push` operator you're currently using is intended to add a value to an array, so that won't get the job done here.

If you're wanting to update a document with a new property, you'll want to use the `$set` operator:

```
db.test.update({contactNumber: "xxx"}, {$set: {address: {country: "India", city: "Blore"}}})
```

Answer (score -1):

please find the below code, its working as expected

worked !!

cmiw !!

```js
db.getCollection('PetCare').update(
  {"email" : "david@gmail.com"},
  {"$set":
    {"userDetails.address":
      {"country":"India","city":"Blore"}
    }
})
```

Comment: Aside from a different property to look up a document (which is not the same as the OP specified), this is identical to an already-posted, upvoted, accepted answer from almost 5 years ago.